# Should pyflakes detect "keyword argument repeated" SyntaxError?

Tags: python, pyflakes

I'm using pyflakes to try and catch errors in a text editor within a PyQt application.
I notice that it doesn't recognize that passing duplicate arguments to a function call results in a SyntaxError as below:

```
pyflakes.api.check("def f(x=0):pass; f(x=1,x=2)")
```

Is this a bug, or am I misunderstanding what pyflakes should be used for?

Comment: Worth noting that `ast.parse` doesn't have a problem with `f(x=1, x=2)` either. One could argue that detecting duplicate names like this is a semantic error and not a syntax error that a parser should catch, but it certainly seems like something `pyflakes` could and should catch.

Comment: (And detecting a *duplicatation* of keyword arguments seems like something that is easier than, for example, detecting keyword arguments with no corresponding parameter.)